# Why didn't Mordechai keep Mitzvos?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

It says [in the Megilla](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%90%D7%A1%D7%AA%D7%A8_%D7%92_%D7%92) "ויאמרו עבדי המלך אשר בשער המלך למרדכי מדוע אתה עובר את מצות המלך" - "The servants of the King (who were in the King's gates) asked Mordechai 'Why do you go against the command of the king'"?

It's known that "the King" in the Megilla refers to Hashem. Why did Mordechai do an Aveira?

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: [Thereafter asked seriously.](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15093)

Answer (score 9):

Well Mordechai had the Jews fast on Pesach.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to say?

Comment: And they didn't eat a k'zais of matza.  That's why Hashem's servants asked madua atta over eis matzos hamelech.