# Why didn't Mordechai keep Mitzvos -- serious edition

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, megillat-esther

It says in the Megilla "ויאמרו עבדי המלך אשר בשער המלך למרדכי מדוע אתה עובר את מצות המלך" - "The servants of the King (who were in the King's gates) asked Mordechai 'Why do you go against the command of the king'"?

It's known ([Esther Rabbah 3:10](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37460&st=&pgnum=186)) that "the King" in the Megilla refers to Hashem. Why did Mordechai do an Aveira?

Comment: inspired by http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15059/why-didnt-mordechai-keep-mitzvos#comment28971_15059

Comment: This question would be more robust if you could [edit] in a source to back up the equation between "the king" and Hashem.

Comment: Question:  Should we ask this for all the places in the Megillah where "King" referring to Hashem doesn't make sense?

Comment: @avi, I think so.

Comment: @msh210 Ok, I started  http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15119/how-could-these-people-see-gds-face-and-not-die

http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15119/how-could-these-people-see-gds-face-and-not-die

Comment: @msh210 I think not. Certainly not before anyone actually sources this claim. And even when they do, it is clearly meant as midrash and will lead to some very strange readings in certain places, as evidenced by avi's questions. I'm not sure there is value in reading the midrash to the logical extreme here.

Comment: @DoubleAA, Couldn't find a source for the fact that "king" == God *always*, but found three times that Esther Rabba uses the analogy: Esther Rabba 3:15, 4:10, 10:1.

Comment: @avi, courtesy ping.

Comment: @jake That's fine. I never said it couldn't be used as a technique in midrash, just that applying it everywhere leads to some very strange conclusions.

Comment: @DoubleAA, Found it. Gra on Esther (derech remez): `ואמרו חכמינו ז"ל במדרש כל מקום שנאמר המלך סתם הוא הקדוש ברוך הוא וכל מקום שנאמר אחשורוש באחשורוש ממש מדבר`. No idea what midrash he's referring to, though. Maybe he's just generalizing the above references from Esther Rabba.

Comment: @jake +1 Good find. But my above point still stands about taking this medrash to literally.

Comment: @DoubleAA, First, the Gra is probably referring to [Esther Rabba 3:10](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37460&st=&pgnum=186), which I didn't see before (and turns out the Zohar also states this fact). Second, nobody is claiming to take this too literally. The claim is just that ***on some level***, there is a reference to God included; not that we are to take it out of the context of referring to Achashverosh.

Comment: @jake +1 again and great work with the source. The source says that when it says למלך by itself it can be kodesh or chol. So it agrees with me that we shouldn't seek to understand every instance of למלך as referring to God.

Comment: @Jake now I can add the source to my other questions.

Comment: @DoubleAA, I would translate, "And all the times we find 'the king' alone, it is being used as holy **and** profane." That is, it of course refers to Achashverosh, but also is referring to God, but on a deeper not-as-contextual level.

Comment: @DoubleAA I agree with Jake, it's an AND not an OR.

Comment: @Jake I agree with DoubleAA, the principle shouldn't be applied except for where the principle is already applied.  Sort of like a Gzera Shava.

Comment: Ok, new nitpick question, perhaps the Midrash only means the word "L'Melech", and not "HaMelech", or stam "Melech"?? And there is a mistake here in the text of the Gra?

Comment: @avi, Not sure what you mean by "where the principle is already applied". Do you mean explicitly applied in that explanation is given by the midrash how that particular reference refers to God? Does not the above-cited midrash have `...כל מקום שנאמר`? Also, in regard to "l'melech" vs. "hamelech" or just "melech", I'm not sure, but see Zohar [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=51738&st=&pgnum=378) which has essentially the same rule with "hamelech".

Comment: @Jake I either mean one of two things, and I'm not sure which one yet. Either, Where it is allready recorded in the Midrash, and the Midrash is just using this as "proof" that its allowed to do that. Or 2, In a situation where you can learn some nice drash that fits with other ideas, but not in a situation where all you have is a question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I once heard an explanation - will have to see if I can find the source - that these other servants (Jews, presumably) held with the opinion later expressed by Rambam ([Hil. Yesodei Hatorah 5:1](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=1&hilchos=1&perek=5&hilite=),4) that one who risks his life to keep mitzvos when not required to do so (i.e., when it's not one of the "big three," the non-Jew is doing it for his own benefit, it's not in public, and not at a time of religious persecution) is "liable for his own death."

In this case, then, the bowing wasn't being commanded as an act of idolatrous homage (or, even if it was, it might have been a case of עובד מיראה - see [Tosafos to Sanhedrin 61b](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=24&daf=61b&format=pdf), ד"ה רבא). They thus protested that Mordechai is transgressing the halachah in endangering his life for this purpose.

(His reply, then, was אשר הוא יהודי - he is a prominent Jew and as such has to hold himself to a higher standard to make a public kiddush Hashem - see the second answer of Tosafos ibid.)

Comment: It is true that in a case such as this the straight and dry halacha is to bow and not be killed, however being that all the other jews were bowing , Mordechai felt the need to protest. In the same way, Chananya Mishael and Azaryah refused to bow to a statue of Nevuchadnetzar even though strictly speaking it was not avoda zara (i forgot the source for that) being that they were not to worship the statue but show subservience to nevuchadnetzar.

Answer (score 7):

My first guess would be: "the servants of the King", i.e. the other rabbinic leaders, asked Mordechai why he violated the will of the King by abandoning his rabbinic role and getting involved with politics.

Answer (score 6):

Even if an unqualified "king" in the Megillah refers to Hashem, the instance you are citing is a quote of Achashverosh's servants. *They* were surely referring to Achashverosh.

Comment: Hmmm... but as @YDK pointed out in the non-serious version of this question, the "servants of the king" should actually be the servants of Hashem...

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the down votes in [my other](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15119/how-could-haman-see-gds-face-and-live) two [questions](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15118/why-were-the-jews-punished-for-going-to-gds-banquet), I would say that the principle (that 'the King' in the Megillah refers to Hashem) can not be universally applied.

And as the accepted answer proves, Mordechai did not actually "go against the command of Hashem"